# storing numbers as varchar

Tags: mysql

Is it ok to store numbers as varchar?

What's the difference between

`int 123456789012` and `varchar 123456789012` ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No, it's almost always a bad idea.

- will use more space
- indexes will not perform as well
- you can't do arithmetic
- the data is not self-validating because of type
- auto-model generators will give you string type instead of numeric
- aggregates like SUM will no longer work
- the output may sort incorrectly
- you will need to CAST to use it as a number, causing performance hit
- etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can store leading zeroes to a varchar that you can't do with integer columns (eg. it is possible to have difference between `123` and `0000123`). For example zip codes in some countries. However, if you need to do that, then you are really dealing with textual information that should have varchar column. For example, phone numbers or zip codes should definitely go to a varchar column.

Otherwise if you are using your data like numbers (adding them together, comparing them, etc.) then you should put it into integer column. They consume far less space and are faster to use.

Comment: The leading zeroes issue can also be a disadvantage.  I recently ran into a situation on a project where, because of how the Java code had handled it, one table had leading zeroes and the other did not.  This made it more difficult to do joins on this column.  The data was a number and so should probably have been stored as such instead of as a varchar.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do calculations with columns declared as varchar, so numeric types should be used. And since your SQL query is a string anyway, MySQL does all the conversion for you (that doesn't mean that you don't need to validate user provided values, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I think is ok to store numbers as varchar, as long as you don't want to make calcs with it.

For example, a phone number or zip codes would be better to store in varchar fields because you could format them.

Comment: I would store things like phone numbers, and only things like phone numbers, as varchar, as they are not really numbers as such. You don't do maths on phone numbers.  However when deciding data types foe fields you should always default to using numerical types over varchar unless you can think of a good reason not to because going from varchar to numeric is far more difficult than the other way round.