# Mysql char vs varchar vs int storage

Tags: mysql

I have a column which always stores 5 digit value (eg: 10100, 60200, 30100 etc). I am in a confusion to which data-type should be good to use (char(5) or varchar(5) or smallInt). As I understand smallint only takes 2 bytes, how many bytes would char(5) and varchar(5) take? And which data-type would be better for my scenario in terms of both performance and storage?

Comment: [The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [storing numbers as varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008371/storing-numbers-as-varchar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 bytes of data = a number from 0 to 65,535 if unsigned or from -32,768 to 32,767 if signed. (unsigned= non-negative values, singed=range of negative to positive).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/integer-types.html

Using a medium int (0 to 16,777,215 unsigned, -8,388,608 to 8,388,607 signed) will guarantee accepted values of any 5 digit number and is what I suggest using, since it requries only 3 bytes of data versus a varchar/char of 5. If you must use characters, and you know that there will be no more than 5 or less than 5 characters, it's good practice to use `char` over `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it depends what is the type of 5 digit code. If its number than choose `mediumint`, if string than choose `char` for easy manipulate for future action. Also consider the size of table

Answer (score 0):

Nobody ever talks about 'the storage is on a disk' and asking the computer to retrieve a file from the disk is ... well, disks run at 100's of thousands of bytes/second - CPU's run at *billions* of operations per second ... this load  (asking the computer to go get a record) is similar to asking your chubby mate to run to the local shop for some cheap food [a Slurpee].

> "Yeah, OK, I'll be back in a while - don't do anything until I get back."

No one mentions that a varchar is an int, charstring.  So varchar(3) is 7 bytes not 3.

Ok, I've only going to have 5000 entries.

And I'm going to have 126 billion.

Yeah but disk space is cheap - but not when it comes to asking for the disk to store or return the data.  Disk write/reads are usually in 2k or 4k blocks.  The first rule ever hammered into me (at play school) was if your table is approaching 10 columns you need to stop and re-think your design.

True story - cust-table:

> ```
> id, fname, lname, sex, dob, address X5(street,city,zip,country), phone X5(with notes), comments and a couple of others.
> ```

Size: 2488 bytes.

Required 2 disk fetches to return record - please go get 2 Slurpees, 1 at a time.

Also searching a DB for an INT is so much faster than searching a CHAR it's not even funny.  IE storing a phone number as a, say, varchar(48) and doing a search when the number has been input as: (719)123-4567 or as 7191234567 or as 719.123.4567 or as '719 1234567 sisters phone'.   Someone please write me a good query.  INTs, ENums etc.

If your table is say 100 bytes long and your computer uses 4k records you can get 40 customers per slurpee instead of 80% of a customer.  It's a 'relational' DB.  That means the cust.name table has a relation to the cust.phone, to the cust.address, to the cust.comments.

Toot, toot...

Comment: fascinating as this diatribe is, it doesn't really answer the question and just lectures on the vague topic. You make various mistakes in your statements and would do well to heavily edit this answer. As well a providing references. Cheers.