# What is the best way to store user editable configuration options?

Tags: php, database-design

This is something that I have been wondering about for a while, and now that I am about to begin another project that requires this, I can't help but wonder if I am doing this the "right way".

Basically, in my API for, in this instance, an enterprise phone system - our client will be able to toggle several options like "forward calls to interactive menu" or modify the spoken greeting that callers hear.

Typically I handle something like this by creating a table in a MySQL database that only has one row that is updated each time the users makes a change to something.

I can't help but feel like this is overkill. Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: Configuration settings ought to go in two places: One for per-application / global settings. And another set for per-user or function settings, which since they need to be associated to something, do belong in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a global setting, that is, not user specific, I'd recommend two tables. One is your list of available settings with their definitions with a `SettingID` and the other table is just two fields: the [foreign key](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/7272/foreign-key) `SettingID` and what the setting is set to.

If the settings are something that each user can set for themselves, simply add `UserID` to the second table.

Using two tables like this, so that each new setting is a new row, is more [normalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql) then the way you suggested. It allows you to have your PHP code add settings or modify settings without having to modify your MySQL Database structure.

```
SettingsList
-----------
SettingID (Auto-increment)
SettingName
SettingDescription

UserSettings
------------
UserID (if using this field, make a compound primary key from SettingID and UserID)
SettingID (SettingsList foreign key, UserSettings primary key if not using UserID)
Setting
```

Comment: Love this, thank you!

Comment: I do have one question though - what data type do you use for the setting in UserSettings? Some settings are boolean values, some aren't, is VarChar the way to go?

Comment: @anwyatt Data types aren't my forte, but based off of what you just said, I'd say yes, `varchar` for this example only. You can't really do anything with numbers in `varchar`, such as sorting or addition, but for a `Settings` table you may not be doing anything except checking if it is 1 or 0. See this for more on integers in varchar fields: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008371/storing-numbers-as-varchar